# WCF Generic FaultException Not Populating SOAP Body Detail Element

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

When I attempt to throw a `FaultException<T>`, if I generate the Message manually, I get correct SOAP message. However, when I throw the `FaultException<T>` from my method on the server, I do not get a correct SOAP message. The SOAP message has a Header / Action value of http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault, and my Body / Fault / Detail element is missing completely.

Please have a look at the important sections of my code.

The Service Contract

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://namespace.com/fault")]
public interface IFaultService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    [FaultContract(typeof (MyFault))]
    void ThrowFaultException();
}
```

The implementation
(The message_fault and message are manually created for testing only)

```
    public class FaultService : IFaultService
{
    public void ThrowFaultException()
    {
        var fault = new MyFault("This is from the service");
        var fault_exception = new FaultException<MyFault>
            (fault,
             "Fault Service Reason",
             FaultCode.CreateReceiverFaultCode("FaultCodeName","http://namespace.com/fault"),
             "http://namespace.com/fault/IFaultService/ThrowFaultExceptionMyFaultFault");

                    var message_fault = fault_exception.CreateMessageFault();
        var message = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressing10, message_fault,
                                            fault_exception.Action);

        throw fault_exception;
    }
}
```

The Data Contract

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://namespace.com/fault")]
public class MyFault
{
    public MyFault(string Message)
    {
        this.Message = Message;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

The web.config system.serviceModel section

```
<system.serviceModel>   
    <bindings>   
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBindingNoSecurity">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
   <services>
      <service name="FaultService">
        <endpoint address="ws"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingNoSecurity"
                  bindingNamespace="http://namespace.com/fault"
                  contract="IFaultService"
                  name="ws">
        </endpoint> 
      </service>
    </services>
...
</system.serviceModel>
```

Manually generated SOAP message

```
{<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://namespace.com/fault/IFaultService/ThrowFaultExceptionMyFaultFault</a:Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
      <s:Code>
        <s:Value>s:Receiver</s:Value>
        <s:Subcode>
          <s:Value xmlns:a="http://namespace.com/fault">a:FaultCodeName</s:Value>
        </s:Subcode>
      </s:Code>
      <s:Reason>
        <s:Text xml:lang="en-US">Fault Service Reason</s:Text>
      </s:Reason>
      <s:Detail>
        <MyFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://namespace.com/fault">
          <Message>This is from the service</Message>
        </MyFault>
      </s:Detail>
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>}
```

But the actual SOAP that comes across is

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<s:Header>
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</a:Action>
<a:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:a3587103-953a-43f6-9691-951c21de8418</a:RelatesTo>
<ActivityId CorrelationId="23bf0a82-f4ac-4227-85ab-600f6ffe6a6f" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">a0945fa9-f5a3-4958-8682-097a8315f0dc</ActivityId>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
<s:Fault>
<s:Code>
<s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value>
</s:Code>
<s:Reason>
<s:Text xml:lang="en-US">Fault Service Reason</s:Text>
</s:Reason>
</s:Fault>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try to generate svclog file by adding System.Diagnostics tag in your web.config file. So that you will get exact issues.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I have not included the diagnostics tag in my sample, but I indeed do have it in the config, and I am not able to discover anything more regarding the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, chalk this one up to experience...

There was an implementation of `IErrorHandler` that was being added to the service in code, during the build up of the services for Dependency Injection. That implementation of the `ProvideFault` method converted all exceptions and faults to the non-generic fault that was returned to the client.

Once that implementation was corrected and the service references refreshed, everything worked as expected.